# Can i turn a light switch into an outlet?

Tags: electrical

Ok so here's the deal, I have a light that is controlled by two switches. One is in my bathroom and the other is in my hallway where the light is located.  I would like to eliminate the switch in the bathroom and replace it with an outlet that is hot all the time.  First of all, can this even be done?  If so how do I go about doing this.

Comment: Maybe.  Probably.

Comment: Where is this light, and can you get us photos of the inisdes of the boxes involved?

Comment: Whether and exactly how you can do this depends on which items are currently connected by cables and where the power comes in to the circuit. If power is delivered to one of the switches then your proposal is possible. If power comes in to the lamp  first and there is no cable between the switches then your proposal is possible. If power comes in to the lamp first, and the lamp is cabled to one of the switches, and there is a cable between the switches, then the existing number of conductors is not sufficient to do what you want, and you will need to pull another wire.

Comment: A.I.Brevelri this should be an answer.

Comment: @Ed: Well if Doug comes back with the info on what cables go where then I'll answer the second part of his question, i.e. how to wire it. If he doesn't come back in 24 hrs then I'll make my comment an answer.

Comment: Doug, you've edited your post from a duplicate account. Please log in as you before further activity.

Comment: What is your location? The answers so far seem to indicate that this is allowable in the US. From my (admittedly limited) experience I do not believe running an outlet from a lighting circuit would be legal in the UK, but I could be wrong. It is certainly the case that all wiring in a bathroom in the UK must be done by a certified electrician, which I somehow doubt you are.

Comment: Also, is there a small appliance circuit already in this bathroom?  If there isn't, you may have to pull a new 20A homerun anyway...

Answer (score 1):

**First, is this legal?**. NEC requires switches in certain specific locations.   What's more, some cities also require switches in cetain locations.   Not least, that's so emergency responders can get the lights on, so an EMT can treat you, or a cop doesn't shoot your son because she can't see that's a computer mouse.  Run this by your electrical inspector.

Ok then.

Turn off the circuit.  Look inside the lamp box. Is there 3-wire  (black white red) cable there?

We know there is 3-wire cable inside the switches, because that's how those switches work.

If this is on conduit we'll have to revisit.  But assuming this is done in cable... The 3 colors are always black white red.   Right mow the colors mean gibberish.  We will give the colors meaning.  And that means every place those 3-wire cables go, **must be rewired**.  The new meanings will be:

- Black -- always-hot (no surprise there)
- White -- actual neutral
- Red - switched-hot

You must studiously follow this code everywhere in this network of 3-wire cable, or you'll get the sparky boomy.  now each device gets wired to the wires it wants:

- switches get connect 2 wires to always-hot **black** and switched-hot **red**. If you are reusing 3-way switches, make sure to use a black screw, a brass will go unused.
- receptacles get always-hot **black** on the brass screws, and neutral **white** on the silver screws.
- lamps take switched-hot **red** and neutral **white**.   They usually have pigtail wires; the black or brown wire is switched-hot (red).  The white or light blue wire on the lamp goes to neutral.

After that, you wirenut-join all wires of the same color (remembering one lamp wire counts as red).

If you have any single wires left dangling, put a smaller wire-nut on them and tape them to keep the wirenut from falling off (they love to fall off singles).

Answer (score 1):

Whether and exactly how you can do this depends on which items are currently connected by cables and where the power comes in to the circuit.

If power is delivered to one of the switches then your proposal is possible. If power comes in to the lamp first and there is no cable between the switches then your proposal is possible.

If power comes in to the lamp first, and the lamp is cabled to one of the switches, and there is a cable between the switches, then the existing number of conductors is not sufficient to do what you want without pulling another wire. In particular, you will need to replace the 12/2wG between the lamp and the switch with 12/3wG.

---

This is the most likely of the nine ways that a three-way single-light would commonly be connected:

[image: three-way: lamp -- switch(power) -- switch]

If your cabling looks like this then you can change the bathroom switch to an outlet like this:

[image: 15A outlet on a lighting circuit]

Note that you don't have to purchase a two-way switch. Just use one of the traveler terminals and ignore the other.

Other cases would be handled similarly. Basically you abandon the original purposes of the wires and re-use them to construct two adjacent circuits.

I have not drawn in the fault ground wires. These are always just connected all together and connected to every metal junction box and to every ground screw that you can identify.

---

A final word: using electricity near water, as in a kitchen or bathroom, is considered particularly dangerous. Make every attempt to properly ground your new outlet. At the very minimum, use only GFCI outlets in bathrooms, kitchens, and laundries.

Comment: If power comes into the light first with a 3 way switch, then there needs to be a /3 cable to each switch location (either line or load + both travellers need to be present at the switch location)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Correct -- assuming there is no cable running between the switches, i.e. assuming **switch====light(power)====switch**. But also possible is **light(power)------switch====switch**, with the entire three-way replacing the switch in a simple switch loop.